# Use multiple Child Of constraints in one bone and animation

Tags: animation, bones, constraints

I have a model and rigged this model then i added 2 Child Of constraints to one of the bones and in timeline i want to change parent but when i do this , bone and attached mesh go to other place and everything runs out. How to fix it?

Comment: Could you use regular Parenting instead (of child of Contraints)? For this use Ctrl+P with two selected Objects, where the Parent is the active object (last selected) and the Child is the other Object

Comment: i want to change parenting in animation

Comment: Do you use keyframes on the influence slider to change the parent? If yes, this probably causes the problem. Because if you reduce the influence of the first parent zero, while you increase the influence of the new parent, the reduction of the old parent will set the position to the default position again instead of leaving it where it is. To solve this i think you can just keep the old parent on 1 while setting the new parent to 1. Maybe you need a different solution, depending what exact behaviour you want to achieve.